# When someone clicks on a <p> tag it should redirect on another page and display items only with property is_hit === true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I already did navigation on another page "catalog" but don't know how to display items with is_hit == true property only after clicking that

tag

{navigate(links.catalog);        window.scrollTo(0, 0);}}>Показать еще

i already have displayed items there with is_hit == true and without is_hit, but when i clicked that

tag on the main page changes should happen on another "catalog" page like it should
remove all items without is_hit and display only items with is_hit

here is part of my code of mainpage:

Хиты продаж
                        
                            
                                {mainPageHits.map((item) =>  )}
                            
                        
                  Показать еще

i already tried some stuff but nothing is working

i would appreciate any help thx )

here is my code of whole catalog page:

```
import SideBarFilter from '../../components/UI/Catalog/SideBarFilter/SideBarFilter.jsx'
import CardItem from '../../components/UI/Catalog/CardItem/CardItem.jsx'
import {asyncGetProducts} from '../../redux/slices/getProductsSlice.jsx'
import SideBar from '../../components/UI/Catalog/SideBar/SideBar.jsx'
import Loading from '../../components/Base/Loading/Loading.jsx'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {links} from '../../links/links.jsx'
import classes from './Catalog.module.sass'
import axios from 'axios';


export default function Catalog() {
    const {products, loading} = useSelector(state => state.getProductsSlice)
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState(6);
    const [sortingType, setSortingType] = useState('priceDesc');
    const [filteredProducts, setfilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  
    const handleShowMore = () => {
        setVisibleItems(prevVisibleItems => prevVisibleItems + visibleItems)
    }

    const applyFilters = (minPrice, maxPrice) => {
        const filtered = products.filter(item => item.price >= minPrice && item.price <= maxPrice)
        setfilteredProducts(filtered)
    }

    const sortProducts = (type, productsToSort) => {
        const sortedProducts = [...productsToSort];

        switch (type) {
            case 'priceDesc':
                sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
                break;
            case 'priceAsc':
                sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
                break;
            case 'popularity':
                sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => b.popularity - a.popularity);
                break;
            case 'rating':
                sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return sortedProducts;
    };
                                                   
       



    useEffect(() => {
  
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/')
            .then(response => {
            
                console.log(response.data.results.filter(product => product.is_hit ===true))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            });
    }, []);



                                        
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(asyncGetProducts())
    }, [dispatch])

    useEffect(() => {
        setfilteredProducts(products);
    }, [products]);

    if (loading) return <Loading/>

    return (
        <div className={classes.catalog}>
            <div className={'container'}>
                <div className={classes.catalog_menuBar}>
                    <div className={classes.catalog_menuBar_nav}>
                        <ul>
                            <li className={classes.catalog_menuBar_nav_br1}
                                onClick={() => navigate(links.mainPage)}>Главное
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <svg width='23' height='24' viewBox='0 0 23 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                                    <path d='M13.8286 5.93018L19.6457 12.0002L13.8286 18.0702M3.354 12.0002H19.4828'
                                          stroke='#B0B0B0' strokeWidth='1.5' strokeMiterlimit='10' strokeLinecap='round'
                                          strokeLinejoin='round'/>
                                </svg>
                            </li>
                            <li className={classes.catalog_menuBar_nav_br2}>Каталог</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.catalog_inner}>
                    <div className={classes.catalog_inner_left}>
                        <div className={classes.catalog_inner_left_sideFilter}>
                            <SideBar sortingType={sortingType} setSortingType={setSortingType} applyFilters={applyFilters}/>
                            <SideBarFilter/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.catalog_inner_right}>
                        <div className={classes.catalog_inner_right_itemsRow}>
                            {sortProducts(sortingType, filteredProducts).slice(0, visibleItems).map((item) =>
                                <CardItem key={item.id} item={item} />
                            )}
                        </div>
                        {products && visibleItems < products.length && (
                            <button className={classes.catalog_inner_right_showBtn} onClick={handleShowMore}>
                                Показать еще
                            </button>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please may you fix the question formatting? Also make sure the added code is a [mcve].

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you are trying to do is with a [GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) request - basically a question mark(?) followed by structured information for the page. In the target page you should get the URL GET information (other links on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and elsewhere can show you how to do this in JavaScript) and use this information for showing/hiding content